# Improve SQL query efficiency - tried indexing, cursor and parallelism

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, cursor, query-performance

this query is taking between 6 1/2 - 8 hours depending on whether I use indexed table or cursor. I recently learned about parallelism (OPTION(USE HINT('ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE'), but that does not seem to help. It is slower than if I don't use in the first query. I have to admit that I don't fully understand the use of parallelism.

The problem I am dealing with is that I am inner joining one large table
(SS_DB.dbo.Path_Statistics_wBatchId) containing 11 MM records with a smaller table (SS_DB.dbo.sfactors) as two instances. The smaller table has 250K records. So, the query is possibly running against 3 trillion records (11 M x 250K). I was able to complete the query and the resulting database (SS_DB.dbo.Path0_test) had 550M records.

Would you provide any suggests to improve performance of either of the two queries below or any other approach please?

These are the two approaches I tried: one without cursor and no index (in fact index is causing more problem) and one with cursor.

```
       select
              fi.ISO
              ,fi.BatchId
              ,sf_sr.constraint_name
              ,fi.Source as SOURCENAME
              ,fi.Sink as SINKNAME
              ,fi.TOU
              ,fi.Source + '_' + fi.Sink + '_' + fi.TOU as ftr_path
              ,round((a.ACP_$MWH - b.ACP_$MWH),4) LSP
              ,coalesce(sf_sr.SFValue,0) - coalesce(sf_sn.SFValue,0) as pathsf
              , sf_sr.SFValue as sr_sf
              , sf_sn.SFValue as sn_sf
              ,sf_sr.CID
              ,(fi.wrr_rev+fi.wrr_pl+fi.cumlroi) score
              ,maxrevmwh, avgrevmwh, minrevmwh, posovertotalrev, wrr_rev, sumposrev, sumnegrev, totalrev, wrr_pl, sumwin, sumloss, cumlroi, totalpl, totalcost,
              posrevcntpct, negrevcntpct, winpct, losspct, avgpl, avgcost, avgposrev, avgnegrev, rr_pl, maxcostmwh, maxplmwh, avgcostmwh, avgplmwh, mincostmwh,
              minplmwh, trades, stdevpl, stdevWin, stdevLoss, stdevrev, stdevposrev, stdevnegrev, stdevposrevmwh, stdevnegrevmwh, maxdate, mindate, Sortino_rev,
              Sharpe_rev, Sortino_pl, Sharpe_pl, obl0, obl5, obl10, obl15, obl20, obl25, obl30, obl35, obl40, obl45, obl50, obl55, obl60, obl65, obl70, obl75,
              obl80, obl85, obl90, obl95, obl100, opt0, opt5, opt10, opt15, opt20, opt25, opt30, opt35, opt40, opt45, opt50, opt55, opt60, opt65, opt70,
              opt75, opt80, opt85, opt90, opt95, opt100
       INTO SS_DB.dbo.Path0_test
       from  SS_DB.dbo.Path_Statistics_wBatchId fi with(NOLOCK) 
       inner join SS_DB.dbo.sfactors sf_sr on sf_sr.PNode_Name = fi.Source
       inner join SS_DB.dbo.sfactors sf_sn on sf_sn.PNode_Name = fi.Sink
                     and sf_sr.constraint_name = sf_sn.constraint_name
                     and sf_sr.contingency = sf_sn.contingency
                     and sf_sr.SFDate = sf_sn.SFDate
                     and sf_sr.CID = sf_sn.CID
                     and abs(sf_sr.SFValue - sf_sn.SFValue)>=0.001          
       inner join SS_DB.dbo.LSP a on fi.Source = a.SourceSink and fi.TOU = a.TOU_Mod
       inner join SS_DB.dbo.LSP b on fi.Sink = b.SourceSink and fi.TOU = b.TOU_Mod
       and fi.ISO= 'MISO'
       --where fi.BatchId <50
       OPTION(USE HINT('ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE'));
```

This query is using cursors:

```
DECLARE @ig as cursor;
DECLARE @batch as int = 1;

set @ig = cursor for 
select distinct fi.BatchId from SS_DB.dbo.Path_Statistics_wBatchId fi --where fi.BatchId < 100;

open @ig;

fetch next from @ig into @batch;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0


begin
    PRINT @batch;
       
INSERT INTO SS_DB.dbo.Path0
       select
              fi.ISO
              ,fi.BatchId
              ,sf_sr.constraint_name
              ,fi.Source as SOURCENAME
              ,fi.Sink as SINKNAME
              ,fi.TOU
              ,fi.Source + '_' + fi.Sink + '_' + fi.TOU as ftr_path
              ,round((a.ACP_$MWH - b.ACP_$MWH),4) LSP
              ,coalesce(sf_sr.SFValue,0) - coalesce(sf_sn.SFValue,0) as pathsf
              , sf_sr.SFValue as sr_sf
              , sf_sn.SFValue as sn_sf
              ,sf_sr.CID
              ,(fi.wrr_rev+fi.wrr_pl+fi.cumlroi) score
              ,maxrevmwh, avgrevmwh, minrevmwh, posovertotalrev, wrr_rev, sumposrev, sumnegrev, totalrev, wrr_pl, sumwin, sumloss, cumlroi, totalpl, totalcost,
              posrevcntpct, negrevcntpct, winpct, losspct, avgpl, avgcost, avgposrev, avgnegrev, rr_pl, maxcostmwh, maxplmwh, avgcostmwh, avgplmwh, mincostmwh,
              minplmwh, trades, stdevpl, stdevWin, stdevLoss, stdevrev, stdevposrev, stdevnegrev, stdevposrevmwh, stdevnegrevmwh, maxdate, mindate, Sortino_rev,
              Sharpe_rev, Sortino_pl, Sharpe_pl, obl0, obl5, obl10, obl15, obl20, obl25, obl30, obl35, obl40, obl45, obl50, obl55, obl60, obl65, obl70, obl75,
              obl80, obl85, obl90, obl95, obl100, opt0, opt5, opt10, opt15, opt20, opt25, opt30, opt35, opt40, opt45, opt50, opt55, opt60, opt65, opt70,
              opt75, opt80, opt85, opt90, opt95, opt100
       from  SS_DB.dbo.Path_Statistics_wBatchId fi with(NOLOCK) 
       inner join SS_DB.dbo.sfactors sf_sr on sf_sr.PNode_Name = fi.Source
       inner join SS_DB.dbo.sfactors sf_sn on sf_sn.PNode_Name = fi.Sink
                     and sf_sr.constraint_name = sf_sn.constraint_name
                     and sf_sr.contingency = sf_sn.contingency
                     and sf_sr.SFDate = sf_sn.SFDate
                     and sf_sr.CID = sf_sn.CID
                     and abs(sf_sr.SFValue - sf_sn.SFValue)>=0.001          
       inner join SS_DB.dbo.LSP a on fi.Source = a.SourceSink and fi.TOU = a.TOU_Mod
       inner join SS_DB.dbo.LSP b on fi.Sink = b.SourceSink and fi.TOU = b.TOU_Mod
       and fi.ISO= 'MISO'
       where fi.BatchId = @batch

fetch next from @ig into @batch;
end

close @ig;
deallocate @ig;
```

Comment: The `CURSOR` option is going to be *slow*, it's doing things one row by agonising row.. For the other, post the query plan (use past the plan) so we can understand what's going on.

Comment: I also **strongly** recommend qualifying your columns; there are lots of columns there that we have no idea where they are coming from.

Comment: Some table schemas wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: When you join `SS_DB.dbo.sfactors` the second time, you add a bunch of conditions, effectively joining it to itself from the first join (sf_sr). I don't understand the point of that, but it does look like something you should do separately. Especially because you are using a calculation in your join conditions. But without the plan it's difficult to say, please use [past the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), as Larnu indicated.

Comment: Also, neither `OPTION(USE HINT())` nor `with(NOLOCK) ` should be used without fully understanding the implications of them. The engine knows better what its doing than most of us.

Comment: Hi Larnu, how do i share the execution plan? Columns not qualified are from the primary table (SS_DB.dbo.Path_Statistics_wBatchId fi), forgot to qualify since there was no duplication of the columns with the other table.

Comment: @ShyamaSonti HoneyBadger provided the link to Paste The Plan.

Comment: Larnu and HoneyBadger please see my plan here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryIWi08bw, the plan seems to use parallelism even when I don't include the parallelism hint.

Comment: @HoneyBadger an interesting find. If I keep the batch size to 200 in the first query, it finishes in 90 sec. If I increase the batch size to 300, it takes 16 min. With 200 batch size, the query automatically uses parallel processing. However I have 5000 batches. How can I process in 200 batch sizes an iterate 25 times? Is there a query way to doing it? Cursor does not seem to work. Please advise.